# Eclipse git:Remote --> Push OK, but Push to Upstream failed

Tags: eclipse, git

In Eclipse with Git installed, I can successfully push my project using "Team --> Remote --> Push". However, if I use "Team --> Push to Upstream", the following error showed up:

```
https://github.com/yltang/myPrepository.git: https://github.com/yltang/myPrepository.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found
```

Can anybody suggest some solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is because https://github.com/yltang/myPrepository doesn't exist.
https://github.com/yltang/myRepository does.

Simply fix the upstream url in the [Upstream Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Upstream_configuration) and it should work.
 it can be displayed and edited in the [repository configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Repository_Configuration) or by clicking `Show In > Properties` on a branch in the Repositories View.

Comment: Oh, my God. It was just a typo? My deep apology!

Comment: @Tang no problem: it can help others confronted with the same cryptic error message.